# Margin right ignored in bourbon neat?

Tags: css, margin, bourbon, neat

http://cdpn.io/ezIxj

I'm working on a portfolio site and would like each project box to span 4 columns on all layout sizes.  Their width seems to be correct based on the column grid shown. But why do the right margins get ignored by the browser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.project` is indeed the last child in `.project-container` div.

I'm not massively familiar with Burbon - just switched those ( .project and .project-container ) classes around

so now `.project:last-child` properly applies to the last-child

Have a look: http://codepen.io/VarinderS/pen/kwgms